# How to get the confusion matrix with the statistics?

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have used the decision tree to predict my test set. After running my code I get a table which has the results, but I want to use the **confusionMatrix()** command from the `caret` library. I have tried several things, but none has worked. Please see my code:

```
library(rpart)
tree <- rpart(train$number ~ ., train, method = "class")
pred <- predict(tree,test, type ="class")
p <- predict(tree, type="class")
# Confusion Matrix
conf <- table(test$number, pred)


> conf
                pred
                 Problem          Reference
  Problem              0            100
  Reference            0           2782
```

I tried to do this:

```
p <- predict(tree, type="class")
confusionMatrix(p, entiredata$number)
```

**Errors** like **data and reference should be the same type**, so I changed it both to factors with `as.factors()`, then the a**rguments were not the same length**. I searched the web and found similiar questions but they all didn't help me. My final goal is to receive the statistics as the accuracy.

Comment: tree classifier has been built on train data. Try using that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(caret) 
confusionMatrix(p, test$number)
```

Since you `predict` only on the test data, you should compare predictions only on the `test` data, not the whole dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For the confusion Matrix, I am trying to download package `e1071`, but unfortunately, it gives me an error saying it's not a valid installed package...I already installed it with no errors...any ideas?

Comment: Try `confusionMatrix()` from `library(caret)`.

Comment: @nadizan I have tried that as well. Starting R today solved my issue with the problem of not being able to get the e1071 package. But thanks for your help as well!